C++20 modules causing compilation errors in simplest QT application
I decided to get familiar with C++20 features, starting with modules. While doing that, I would like to create a simple GUI application based on QT. But apart from modules support in Cmake being crude at best, I noticed some strange errors, which are obviously caused by usage of modules, though I have no idea where do they come from.
Minimal reproducible example is as follows:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.0)
project(TestProj VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(OUTPUT_BIN_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fmodules-ts ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_BIN_DIRECTORY})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_BIN_DIRECTORY})

# add_custom_target(
#    std_modules ALL
#    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -std=c++20 -g -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header memory
# )

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

add_executable(TestApp main.cpp)
#add_dependencies(TestApp std_modules)
target_link_libraries(TestApp Qt5::Widgets)

main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel hello("Hello world!");

    hello.show();
    return app.exec();
}

If I build this app as it is now (with custom target and its dependency commented out in CMakeLists.txt), then everything works.
But suppose I would like to use something from memory header. As I understand, all headers from std can (should?) be imported as (if they were) modules, like so:
import <memory>;

To do that, hovewer, I need these headers pre-compiled, since Cmake would not prepare them for me. That's what this custom target std_modules is for. But as soon as I try re-build my app with this target and dependency uncommented (before I even add import <memory>; to my code), compilation fails with lots of strange errors:
[main] Building folder: testproj 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /ramdisk/testproj/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [1/3  33% :: 0.575] cd /ramdisk/testproj/build && /usr/bin/g++ -std=c++20 -g -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header memory
[build] [2/3  66% :: 1.859] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/main.cpp.o 
[build] /usr/bin/g++ -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -isystem /usr/include/qt -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -fmodules-ts  -g -std=gnu++20 -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/TestApp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /ramdisk/testproj/main.cpp
[build] In file included from /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:63,
[build]                  from /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/memory:66,
[build] of module /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/memory, imported at /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:71,
[build]         included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qbrush.h:52,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qpalette.h:46,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:48,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qframe.h:44,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qlabel.h:44,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/QLabel:1,
[build]                  from /ramdisk/testproj/main.cpp:2:
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/ext/numeric_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<short unsigned int>’:
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/charconv:533:69:   required from ‘constexpr bool std::__detail::__from_chars_alnum(const char*&, const char*, _Tp&, int) [with bool _DecOnly = true; _Tp = short unsigned int]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/format:277:42:   required from ‘constexpr std::pair<short unsigned int, const _CharT*> std::__format::__parse_integer(const _CharT*, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/format:288:49:   required from ‘constexpr std::pair<short unsigned int, const _CharT*> std::__format::__parse_integer(const _CharT*, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = wchar_t]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/format:471:51:   required from ‘static constexpr std::__format::_Spec<_CharT>::iterator std::__format::_Spec<_CharT>::_S_parse_width_or_precision(iterator, iterator, short unsigned int&, bool&, std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>&) [with _CharT = wchar_t; iterator = const wchar_t*]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/format:509:43:   required from ‘constexpr std::__format::_Spec<_CharT>::iterator std::__format::_Spec<_CharT>::_M_parse_width(iterator, iterator, std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>&) [with _CharT = wchar_t; iterator = const wchar_t*]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/format:904:33:   required from ‘constexpr typename std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>::iterator std::__format::__formatter_int<_CharT>::_M_do_parse(std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>&, std::__format::_Pres_type) [with _CharT = wchar_t; typename std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>::iterator = const wchar_t*]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/format:987:21:   required from ‘constexpr typename std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>::iterator std::__format::__formatter_int<_CharT>::_M_parse(std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>&) [with _Tp = char; _CharT = wchar_t; typename std::basic_format_parse_context<_CharT>::iterator = const wchar_t*]’
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/format:1777:28:   required from here
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/ext/numeric_traits.h:130:3: error: definition of ‘enum __gnu_cxx::__is_integer_nonstrict<__int128 unsigned>::<unnamed>’ does not match
[build]   130 |   _GLIBCXX_INT_N_TRAITS(__int128, 128)
[build]       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/utility:79,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qglobal.h:47,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:43,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:43,
[build]                  from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
[build]                  from /ramdisk/testproj/main.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/ext/numeric_traits.h:57:12: note: existing definition ‘enum __gnu_cxx::__is_integer_nonstrict<__int128 unsigned>::<unnamed>’
[build]    57 |       enum { __width = __value ? sizeof(_Tp) * __CHAR_BIT__ : 0 };
[build]       |            ^
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/ext/numeric_traits.h:130:3: note: ... this enumerator ‘__gnu_cxx::__is_integer_nonstrict<__int128 unsigned>::__value’
[build]   130 |   _GLIBCXX_INT_N_TRAITS(__int128, 128)
[build]       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/ext/numeric_traits.h:57:14: note: enumerator ‘__gnu_cxx::__is_integer_nonstrict<__int128 unsigned>::__width’ does not match ...
[build]    57 |       enum { __width = __value ? sizeof(_Tp) * __CHAR_BIT__ : 0 };
[build]       |              ^~~~~~~
[build] /usr/include/c++/13.2.1/ext/numeric_traits.h:64:53: note: during load of pendings for ‘__gnu_cxx::__is_integer_nonstrict’
[build]    64 |       static_assert(__is_integer_nonstrict<_Value>::__value,
[build]       |                                                     ^~~~~~~
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /ramdisk/testproj/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:01.892
[build] Build finished with exit code 1

It looks like the problem is connected with QT headers including memory header in old-fashioned way, although it somehow seems to map to importing is as module automatically. I doubt this has anything to do with the fact I use QT in particular, I guess the problem is more generic. Still, this disables me from developing my application using modules.
Of course, I could just give up on importing std headers as modules and call it a day. But isn't one of the points of modules to eliminate (or at least limit to minimum) including headers in the code? Why then should I give up on importing std headers like modules? This is more like a pointless workaround than a solution.

import <memory>; is not a named module but a header unit. Support for them is still pretty rough

Support for mixing imports and includes of the standard library has not been implemented yet. There is a workaround that involves creating a header file that defines all of the include guard macros for all of the standard library headers that would be included. It assumes that your c++ standard library implementation uses include guard macros and not #pragma once. This solution is tedious and ugly, but it has worked for me while I wait for mixing standard library imports and includes to be supported.
macro_guards.h:
#ifndef MACRO_GUARDS
#define MACRO_GUARDS

#define _EXT_NUMERIC_TRAITS
// ... Add defines for all headers that will be used

#endif

You must import <memory> (or import std in c++23) and include macro_guards.h before you include the header that is including the standard library, e.g.
import <memory>;
#include "macro_guards.h"
#include <header_that_includes_std_library.h>

Credit to this comment for the idea.
Update:
The day after I posted this answer, Microsoft released a new version of Visual Studio that includes a new version of the STL that includes support for mixing includes and imports, provided the include is before the import. See the "Enhanced Behavior" section of the release notes.

Wrapped the STL in extern "C++" as a temporary workaround to allow #include  to coexist with import std; in the same translation unit, in that order. #4154


The other order, import std; before #include , will still cause compiler errors. We're working on a long-term solution.


Clever, but indeed very ugly and heavily dependent on C++ stdlib implementation. Not exactly what I am looking for. Still, thanks for the info that mixing imports for std with their legacy includes is not supported.

@PookyFan Don't think this will help you much, but I thought it was worth letting you know that Microsoft just released a new version of their STL that added support for mixing #includes and imports, as long as the #include is before the import. See the release notes under "Enhanced Behavior". I'll add an update to the answer in case it helps someone else.
